# Count consecutive elements of the same class until another class appears

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="countme"> </div>
  <div class="countme"> </div>
  <div class="countme"> </div>
  <div class="stophere"> </div>
  <div class="whatever"> </div>
  <div class="countme"> </div>
  <div class="countme"> </div>
  <div class="countme"> </div>
</div>
```

I want to know the number of **countme** divs before any another class appears. `$('.countme').length` does not work, because it gives a result of **6** when the result I'm expecting should be **3** of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the first one, then get the next ones until something else occurs, and add back the first one

```
$('.countme').first().nextUntil(':not(.countme)').addBack().length
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s4rr4/)

Comment: Why `.addBack()`? Simply `.length+1`.

Comment: When selecting `nextUntil`, the `first()` is discarded, new selector and all, so I have to add it back ?

Comment: I think he meant why not adding `1` to the result. Though it will wrongly result in `1` for empty collections.

Comment: @BlackSheep - Oh, of course, just adding 1 to the length would be the same thing, but if the OP or anyone else searching decides to use it for something else, it's all in the collection this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $(".wrapper div").each(function(){

        if($(this).attr('class') == 'countme'){
           count++;
        }else{
            if(count > 0){
               return false;
            }
        }

    });
    alert(count);
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t6JFV/)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please consider adding an explanation; answers are most helpful when they contain both a solution and an explanation.

Comment: Thanks... Ed Cottrell. The problem is i dont speak much english hehehe... But I'll try help with explanation.. :)